# how to show this integral is $\in \mathbb{R}$ (attempt added)

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic  such that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Let $z_0 \in \Omega$  such that $\overline{D_{R}}\left(z_{0}\right) \subseteq \Omega$. Given that for every $z \in \partial D_{R}\left(z_{0}\right)$ $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $$f(z_0)\in \mathbb{R}$$

so I was trying to use cauchy integral theorem : $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D_{R}(z_0)} \frac{f(z)}{z- z_0}dz$$
so I know $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ but I am not sure how should I procced from here

Comment: Spell out the integral in terms of the curve $[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C$, $t\mapsto z_0+R(\cos t+i\sin t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameterize your curve (the boundary of the disk) by $\partial D_R=\{z_0+Re^{it}:0\leq t\leq 2\pi\}$.  With this, your integrand becomes
$$\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}=\frac{f(z)}{Re^{it}}$$
and your measure for integration will be $$dz=iRe^{it}dt$$
So the integral will become
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(z)}{Re^{it}}iRe^{it}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi}f(z)dt\in \mathbb{R}$$

The point to be taken away from this is that for holomorphic functions, their value at a point is dictated by their values on the boundary of a disk containing that point throughout which the function is holomorphic.  This is exactly what the Cauchy integral formula says, and this further drives that point home.